# Android: Specify layout_weight for layout_height and layout_width separately

Tags: android, layout

Question says it all.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is my answer below an answer to your question? If so, please accept/upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weight attribute only has meaning for the orientation of the parent layout.
If you define the parent layout to be horizontal, the weight has meaning for the width of the layout.
If you put a vertical layout within a horizontal layout, you can assign a weight to te vertical layout element, which is for the width, and within the vertical layout you can define weights for child elements that are for the height.
Please read this carefully:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation

Comment: That sounds good, thanks!  But if I have a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation, set the layout_width to 0dp, and specify a layout_weight, this applies the weight to the width.  So your solution is what I was looking for, but the horizontal->width and vertical->height doesn't sound right.